# Equation solving in terms of a parameter in R

Tags: r, equation-solving, parametric-equations

I have the following equation I'd need to solve for η:

[image: equation]

where the parameter θ is unknown (the general problem is to estimate it), and the vector *h* depends on that parameter, and a vector of known values *y*.

What ideally I would like to get is the vector η=η(θ) as a function of the parameter θ so that I can easily use it later.

Comment: If you want a symbolic solution, that will be impossible or very difficult. Write the right hand side of your equation as a function of `theta` and a vector `eta`. And use a solver for systems of nonlinear equations such as `nleqslv` or `BB`. And you will get numerical solutions if your system has a solution.

Comment: a priori the system does have a solution for eta, which is also unique.

Comment: Hoewever the key point is that I need to later use a maximization on another function which depends on eta in order to obtain estimates for theta.

Comment: To me it is not clear, what you are asking: All I read sounds like numerical solution of an equation. Then please provide data if you need further help. If you also want to maximize, you have to specify what you want to maximize and which constraints you have (if at all).

Comment: So eta is an n long vector and you wish to estimate eta and theta? Then you have n+1 parameters you need to estimate. That seems like quite a lot.

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time. For the full question please go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231338/r-implementation-of-the-maximum-empirical-likelihood-estimation-for-l%C3%A9vy-process), as the whole problem is better explained. In this post I just tried to focus on the part that I am stuck, but yes sorry, it lacks information.